# is there any way to auto copy of any new MySQL table to HANA DB through Pentaho?

Tags: php, mysql, pentaho, hana

I have a MySQL DB and I constantly copy my data into Sap HANA DB for analytics. However, MySQL DB is under development and it always emerges new tables. For each new table, I create a matching table in HANA and a new ETL pipeline in Pentaho. It seems a bit silly to me. I guess there should be some way to auto construct the new table in HANA and copy the data from MySQL to HANA for this new table. Is it a valid thinking for Pentaho or still I should do the same as explained?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 1 batch process (job) from which your transformations gets execute and automatically do the process which you are doing manually by executing transformation.

And for Automatically creating new table you can use parametrized approach, and you can set one parameter so when-ever it will find new parameter it will create your table.

And for batch process you can set interval so on that specific time your batch process executes and your transformation runs with it and you can achieve your goal.